# Using FirstOrDefault in a sub query

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

We are having major performance issues with some of our LINQ-to-SQL queries.

We have a Case table, with a one-to-many relationship on CaseStatus (relationship table is CaseCaseStatus)
Although, we want to keep track of all statusses on a case, only the last one really has any value.

We are building a query like follows:

```
IQueryable<Case> results = Repository.GetFullList(); // Returns a Queryable

if(filter.OnlyOpen){
   results = results
      .Where(c => c.CaseCaseStatusses.Any() 
               && c.CaseCaseStatusses.OrderByDescending(cs => cs.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault().Status.IsClosed != true);
}

results.Select(x => Dto(x)).ToList();
```

Basicly we want to know if the last status, has a property "IsClosed == true".

When I monitor my database through the SQL profiler, I can see that the database is being queried when we hit the Select statement, not before. (As intented)
But while the query is being executed, I can see a select query for each case:

```
SELECT [cs0].[Id], [cs0].[CaseId], [cs0].[Note], [cs0].[ShowOnClientPage], [cs0].[StatusId], [cs0].[TimestampUTC], [cs.Status0].[IsClosed] 
FROM [CaseCaseStatusses] AS [cs0] 
INNER JOIN [CaseStatusses] AS [cs.Status0] ON [cs0].[StatusId] = [cs.Status0].[Id]
WHERE [cs0].[CaseId] = <CaseId>
```

Since we have 8000+ records in our Case Table, it does 8000 of above select statements ... while we want 1 single query to be executed. Has this behavior changed in EFCore? I could swear I've done this before and it would output a single query (granted, it was a big unreadable query and not EFCore)

Is there another (better) way to perform these kind of queries?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? `FirstOrDefault in a sub query` is how you thought you'd solve the real problem, not the problem itself. A `SELECT TOP 1` in a subquery isn't necessarily the most efficient way to filter based on first or last value either. Finally, calling both `CaseCaseStatusses.Any()`  and `c.CaseCaseStatusses....` is self-contradictory.  And `IsClosed != true` when the result may be a `NULL` will result in even more problems

Comment: Unfortunately the answer depends on EF Core version. 1.x/2.x use client evaluation and in many cases suffers the aforementioned N + 1 query problem. From the other side in 3.x/5.x it might simply reject to translate and throw exception. So no general advice.

Comment: LINQ-to-WhateverDatabase isn't magic nor a replacment for SQL. It's meant to make querying using an ORM easier. In turn, ORMs are meant to load objects, not perform reporting queries like the one you try to execute. In SQL you can get the first or last value in a result set with `FIRST_VALUE() OVER(...)` or `LAST_VALUE() OVER()`. If you want to find records whose last status isn't closed you can use `LAST_VALUE(IsClosed) OVER(ORDER BY Timestamp desc)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are sharing this *opinion* many times which I kindly disagree. Both LINQ and SQL are query languages, and LINQ-to-somedb **is** supposed to be a strongly typed object oriented SQL replacement. The fact that some implementations fail to do so does not change the idea. Also it meant to be database agnostic, which can't be said for the SQL specific functions you are giving as an example.  It's the LINQ translator job to translate LINQ construct describing the "last item in ordered subset" to the corresponding db/SQL construct.

Comment: @Shadowfox What exact EF Core version are you targeting, what database and provider. Also can you provide repro (e.g. [mre]) since a simple test with similar query with EFC 2.2.6 translates and executes as single SQL query (btw, Linq-to-Sql is totally different framework. As well as EF6. Don't use them as interchangeable),

Comment: @IvanStoev not an opinion. To be a replacement it would have to eliminate the impedance mismatch between relational and object paradigms. ORMs only go so far towards this, and break down in analytic and reporting queries. Even with SQL Server, no LINQ provider ever offered more than basic querying. This is nothing new. Neither Hejlsberg nor any of the LINQ team ever claimed it's a SQL replacement or even that it's intended to be one. The name is `Language Integrated Query` not `Object Query Language`. If anything, F# type providers make a far better job of reducing the mismatch

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It *is* an opinion. Language or Object - does it matter? The important is that it is a Query language. And the `the whole  queryable concept / implementation of LINQ - BCL `IQueryable` interfaces and extension methods are just for that. I don't care what F# is doing since we are speaking about C#. And it generally does it's job. And the "method syntax" is extendable and can easily add missing constructs. As soon as the query provider is willing to do that rather than adding partial support because ... hmm, no good reason other than inability to do it or lack of time.

Comment: @Shadowfox essentially, you're trying to retrieve Case records that aren't closed. It would be a *lot* easier to do this if you used an an `IsClosed` flag on `Case` instead of trying to find the latest status from the status history table. This isn't a case of duplicating information. Despite the name, if `CaseStatusses` contains multiple `Status` values per case, it's a history table containing historical entries, not the current status of a `Case`. If you used temporal tables you could treat the table both as a `current` and historical table

Comment: @Shadowfox which SQL Server version are you using? All current versions (ie 2016 and later) have [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15). If you convert `CaseStatuses` into a temporal table,  you can get the "current" status with a simple join and `CaseCaseStatusses` would become a 1:1 relation. You could write just `Where(c=>c.CaseStatus.Status.IsClosed !=true)`. If you use an explicitly named history table, you'll be able to retrieve all past statues by querying it

Comment: We're using EFCore 2.2.0, SqlServer (2016), Changing our Domain model is NOT an option.

Comment: @IvanStoev I've just upgraded tot EFCore 2.2.6, problem still persists. Time doesn't allow me to provide a code-sample right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, it should work with any EF version.

```cs
var results = 
   from r in results
   from c in r.CaseCaseStatusses
      .OrderByDescending(cs => cs.Timestamp)
      .Take(1)
   where c != null && c.Status.IsClosed != true
   select r;
```